# How to write hidden input field in HTML Template Language (HTL)

Tags: sightly, htl

What is the syntax to include hidden field in HTML Template Language (HTL)?

In jsp we can write

```
<input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value="hiddenValue"/>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. You just add `<input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value="hiddenValue"/>` to your HTL file and that's it. Just like with JSPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do the exact same thing in HTL.

```
<input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value="hiddenValue"/>
```